# Programmatic SchemaUpdate in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-6

I'm trying to run a SchemaUpdate in my Java EE 6 application. In previous Hibernate versions I managed to do so creating an `Ejb3Configuration` and then running a SchemaUpdate. Pretty much like this:

```
Ejb3Configuration cfg = new Ejb3Configuration();
cfg.configure(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, null);
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect.getClass().getName());
Collection<String> entityClassNames = getEntityClassNames(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
for (String className : entityClassNames)
{
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Class.forName(className));
}

EntityManagerFactory factory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

new SchemaUpdate(cfg.getHibernateConfiguration()).execute(true, true);
```

Apparently the class `Ejb3Config` is deprecated and is not supported. So what is the proper way to do a SchemaUpdate with hibernate 4?

Comment: It seems like you're in trouble. According to [HHH-2578](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2578), `Configuration` is being replaced by [`MetadataSources`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/MetadataSources.html) and friends. There is currently no way that i can see to use that to feed a `SchemaUpdate`. I suspect [HHH-6445](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6445) is the issue for fixing this, but it is unresolved, and hasn't been touched in a year.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're using EE 6. Are you therefore using a persistence.xml and all the standard JPA stuff? If not, then that's a mistake, and the first step is to go back and fix that. Using a persistence.xml, you can specify schema update on startup with a property:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="...">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Would that be suitable? Or do you have a partcular reason for doing this manually?

Comment: Actually I want to trigger that functionality manually. The reason is simple. Our application should be able to modify the database schema according to the application model automatically. When ever FK relations are introduced we need hibernate's SchemaUpdate mechanism to create FK-constraints. We don't want to deal with that bit since this is very db vendor specific and already handled by hibernate.